# AngularJS - share variable between two controllers

Tags: angularjs

I have two controllers that have to communicate each other.
The first reference to a video player and the second one to a timeline.

From the first one, I get the `currentTime` of the video playback and I want to pass it to the second one that should move the time-bar as the video is playing.

I tried using the factory to share a variable called `time` between controllers but this doesn't change during the time.

**First Controller**:

```
angular.module('videoCtrl', ['vjs.video'])
  .controller('videoController', ['$scope', 'Timeline', function (scope, Timeline) {
        scope.mediaToggle = {
            sources: [
                {
                    src: 'http://static.videogular.com/assets/videos/videogular.mp4',
                    type: 'video/mp4'
                }
            ],
        };

        //listen for when the vjs-media object changes
        scope.$on('vjsVideoReady', function (e, videoData) {
          videoData.player.on('timeupdate', function () {
            var time = this.currentTime();
            Timeline.setTime(time); // setting the time on factory
          })
        });
    }]);
```

**Second Controller**:

```
angular.module('timelineCtrl', ['mt.media-timeline'])
    .controller('timelineController', function ($scope, Timeline) {
    $scope.time = Timeline.getTime(); // here I'm trying to get the time
  });
```

**Factory**:

```
.factory('Timeline', function(){
    var timelines = [];
    var time = null;
    return {

      getTime: function() {
        return time;
      },

      setTime: function(_time) {
        time = _time;
      }

    }
  });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`time` appears to be a primitive, which means it is returned **byVal** rather than **byRef**.  In other words, each call to `getTime` will return the value that `time` is currently set to, and calls to `setTime` will change the value for future calls, but not for anything that already called it.  This is a classic case of the angular rule, *Always use a dot*.

Try changing `time` to an object instead:

```
.factory('Timeline', function() {
  var timelines = [];
  var time = {
    value: null
  };
  return {

    getTime: function() {
      return time;
    },

    setTime: function(_time) {
      time.value = _time;
    }

  }
});
```

In your HTML, use `{{time.value}}`.

Comment: but this is not updating the time variable in the other controller during playback. I was already able to get the `time` as the page load. I don't need `time` var in the HTML I need in the second controller. For example if I write `console.log(_time)` inside `setTime(_time)` function I get value of the currentTime changing while the video is playing

Comment: this is the result of `console.log(_time)` [Log] 0 (script.js, line 35222)
[Log] 0.125696053 (script.js, line 35222)
[Log] 0.377129754 (script.js, line 35222)
[Log] 0.626557536 (script.js, line 35222)
[Log] 0.87789302 (script.js, line 35222)
[Log] 1.052918579 (script.js, line 35222)

Comment: if the `videoData.player.on('timeupdate',...` is firing, then this object should be continually receiving new `_time`, and saving it into `time.value`.  in **either** the other controller or it's associated HTML, `time.value` should have the last value that was posted by the `videoData` call.

Comment: but if I put a `console.log()` in the second controller I don't get the same result.

Comment: what are you expecting to happen?  a controller is a **constructor function**, it only fires once, so putting a `console.log()` in the controller would only output a value *once*, when the controller is initialized.  If you want to do something every time that `time.value` changes, then you need `$watch`.

Comment: I don't know, this is why I'm asking. I read in other post that $watch isn't the best way.

Comment: what is it ***exactly*** that you are trying to do inside your controller?  using `$watch` isn't a "use it all the time it's the best" kind of solution, so sometimes people will tell you that using it at all is wrong, but that's not right either.  there are situations where it is needed, and there are situations where you can use it but probably shouldn't.  Your question doesn't have enough information about what you are actually trying to accomplish to tell the difference.  Plus, `{{time.value}}` is *implicitly* a `$watch`.

Comment: From the first controller I'm getting the currentTime in seconds of the video playback during time (so while the video is playing) and I want to pass it (as it is, so changing during time) to the second controller that should move a time-bar as the video is playing. If you try a simple video editor you could better understand what I'm trying to do: you have a video preview of what you're creating and a timeline showing the video that you're editing. When you push play the video start playing and a time-bar play horizontally to show you the position of the playback

Comment: So what does the code that updates the time bar look like?  Please update your question with that code.

Comment: nothing, I have a var called `tick` that when change his value move the bar, so if I set `tick = currentTime` the timeline start moving. The problem is that `currentTime` comes from a controller  and `tick` from another

Comment: Ok, but how often are you changing tick?

Comment: I don't know it should change every time `currentTime` change

Comment: If you only need the value in the HTML I suggest using expressions, if you need it in your controller too, because you have to make some other changes you should use `$watch`,because this allows you to react to changes right after they happen.

Comment: It still seems like tick=$scope.time.value should work, in that case...

Comment: It does work, but if he just uses `{{time.value}}` in the template, he has no way of reacting to changes. Of course there are other ways(like specifying a function in the expression, which then retrieves the value and can also handles changes), but I think this would only make it more confusing right now.

Comment: I don't know how else to help here, but I hope you are able to work this out

Comment: I'm trying to make the first controller parent of the second one. So maybe I can access using `$scope.$parent.time`

Comment: While that might work, it still doesn't really allow you to execute code when the value changes. If you do have to do that I suggest using $watch, otherwise you could also use Claies approach, or the one I suggested in the last paragraph of my answer. I wouldn't advise using `$parent`, because it ties your controllers pretty tight together, because one always must be the parent scope of the other.

Answer (score 0):

Saving in `$rootScope` instead of `$scope` would give you the ability to access a variable across all your app and your controllers. But have in mind that creating a large number of $rootScope could affect your app's performance.

Do not forget to inject `$rootScope` into the controller (like you did with $scope), so you can access it.

Comment: This is not recommended at all, you can accidently overwrite the values of `$rootScope` and adding unnecessary `$watch`s

Comment: using `$rootScope` is, in almost every case, an anti-pattern.  This is a case that can be solved by re-organizing the factory.

Comment: Agree. @AlonEitan.

Answer (score 0):

Well as far as I can tell what're doing in the second controller is that you retrieve the value of time on instantiation of the controller. Of course further changes of the value in the service can't be picked up this way. To do that can use `$scope.$watch` in the second controller:

```
angular.module('timelineCtrl', ['mt.media-timeline'])
    .controller('timelineController', function ($scope, Timeline) {
    $scope.time = Timeline.getTime(); //Set the time once so it's not undefined

    $scope.$watch(
      function() {return Timeline.getTime();},
      function(newVal) {$scope.time = newVal;}
    );
});
```

Angular will call the first function in every `$digest` cycle(That's about at least every 10ms if I recall correctly) and will call the second function when a change has been detected. Detailed documentation for `$watch` can be found [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch)

This is one way to do it. You could also add a function to your `$scope`(e.g. `getTime()`), which should return the current time, and then call this function in the HTML template: `{{getTime()}}`. Both ways pretty much work the same way, except that the second one leaves the 'dirty' work to angular(creating watchers and updating values)